# Using a higher order function, return one object value if another value is true (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, higher-order-functions

I have an object:

```
const animals = [
    {name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat'},
    {name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit'},
    {name: 'Wally', species: 'dog'},
    {name: 'Roo', species: 'dog'},
    {name: 'Felix', species: 'cat'},
]
```

I want to use a higher order function such as the filter() method to take the array of animal objects and return an array with just the names of all the dogs i.e. `["Wally", "Roo"]`. My code at the moment returns an array containing the entire object with the species dog in it. See below:

```
const dogArray = animals.filter(function(animal) {
  return animal.species === 'dog';
 })

return dogArray;

// returns
// [{name: "Wally", species: "dog"}, 
// { name: "Roo", species: "dog"}]
```

Comment: Using `reduce` will be efficient here as you're filtering and mapping on the same array.

Comment: Yes, that's how `filter` works. You'll want to additionally `map` that result. You could combine both actions into the same iteration using `reduce`.

Comment: This is a legitimate question and is formatted correctly (well, indentation in the first code block would help). Not sure why you got the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map the elements of the filtered array to their name property:

```js
const animals = [
  {name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit'},
  {name: 'Wally', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Roo', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Felix', species: 'cat'},
]

const dogArray = animals.filter(animal => animal.species === 'dog');

console.log(dogArray.map(dog => dog.name));
```

Or combine the two into one reduce:

```js
const animals = [
  {name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit'},
  {name: 'Wally', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Roo', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Felix', species: 'cat'},
]

let dogArray = animals.reduce((dogs, animal) => {
  if (animal.species === "dog") dogs.push(animal.name);
  return dogs;
}, []);

console.log(dogArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the property with a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const
    animals = [{ name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat' }, { name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit' }, { name: 'Wally', species: 'dog' }, { name: 'Roo', species: 'dog' }, { name: 'Felix', species: 'cat' }]
    dogArray = animals
        .filter(({ species }) => species === 'dog')
        .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(dogArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array, iterate over the existing `dogArray` using a `for` loop, push the names into the new array, and return the new array.

```
const dogArray = animals.filter(function(animal) {
  return animal.species === 'dog';
 })

let dogNames = [];

for (let i in dogArray) {
  dogNames.push(dogArray[i].name);
}

return dogNames;
```

Comment: I'm happy to address any issues the downvoter perceives.

Comment: The downvote probably comes from not explaining what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = [
{name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat'},
{name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit'},
{name: 'Wally', species: 'dog'},
{name: 'Roo', species: 'dog'},
{name: 'Felix', species: 'cat'},
]

var result = animals.filter(val=>val.species=="dog").map(({name})=>name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` followed by `.map()`:

```js
const animals = [
  {name: 'Fluffy', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Crinkle', species: 'rabbit'},
  {name: 'Wally', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Roo', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Felix', species: 'cat'},
];

const dogNames = animals
  .filter(animal => animal.species === 'dog')
  .map(dog => dog.name);

console.log(dogNames);
```